How To Detect Interaction user in other bots
I wanted to make a bot with logger, for example when someone runs /ban  in Carl bot, I want my bot to detect the interaction user who ran this slash cmd in Carl bot. Any idea how without using reference msg??
I used to use reference msg which was good,but not all bots have that
